# MySQL choosing primary key over index

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, query-performance

I have a table with around 600.000 entries and I need to update few very specific entries. The table is:

```
ID (primary)
start (datetime)
end (datetime)
room_id (int)
locked (tinyint, 1)
```

I have created an index with (start, end, room_id), which brought a huge performance boost to my SELECT queries. However, now I'm running the following query:

```
update vacancies
    set locked = 1
    where start >= '2017-11-28 22:00:00'
      and end   <= '2017-11-28 23:00:00'
      and (room_id = 1234 
          or room_id in (select other_room
                     from room_dependencies
                     where first_room = 1234))
```

I believe that this query takes quite a lot of time for what it is doing (~1.5s). I run an EXPLAIN command on MySQL and it returned the following:

[image: EXPLAIN results]

I am not (by far) a DB expert, but I thought it was weird that this query was running a full table scan (FTS) instead of using the INDEX (start, end, room_id). Apparently, it identifies "start" as a viable key, then ignores it, picks the PRIMARY KEY and runs a FTS. So, I followed [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18162141/mysql-uses-primary-key-instead-of-index), removed the PRIMARY KEY and added (start, end, room_id) as a new PRIMARY KEY, but the results were exactly the same (or even worst).

This is a single request that must be made immediately after some other actions on the platform, so it is impossible to queue it and run it as a batch with other updated in a delayed form.

Is there any other way that I can improve the performance of this query?

Thanks!

Comment: What do your other selects look like?  Usually you put columns for which a range is wanted at the end of a multicolumn index (room_id,start,end).  I suspect you either want that or an additional index just on room_id.   Or possibly just saying `update vacancies use index (start) set ...` will be good enough.

Comment: (The '1' after the tinyint has no meaning)

Comment: How many rows have a start time >= '2017-11-28 22:00:00'?  Have you tried `WHERE start >= '2017-11-28 22:00:00' AND start < '2017-11-28 23:00:00' AND end <= '2017-11-28 23:00:00' AND ...`?  The optimizer doesn't intuitively understand that it can eliminate rows that start after your desired end time.

Comment: Why do you need a UNIQUE KEY when there is already a PRIMARY KEY?

Answer (score 0):

MySQL `in` condition doesn't take advantage of the index. Try `inner join` instead.

```
update vacancies
     inner join 
     (select other_room 
           from room_dependencies 
           where first_room = 1234) t2
     on vacancies.room_id = t2.other_room
     set locked = 1
     where start >= ''
           and end <= '';
```

and do the other update with room_id = `1234` alone.

Answer (score 0):

While your start and end values probably specify a small number of rows, because the range is represented by 2 separate attributes in the index, the DBMS would first have to read every single index entry with `start >= '2017-11-28 22:00:00'` before discarding rows which do not satisfy `end   <= '2017-11-28 23:00:00'`. The DBMS knows this would be an expensive operation.

There are 2 routes to solving this problem. One is to divide the range up in a pre-defined set of blocks, then link each of those blocks back to the vacancies table (which is messy and still not very efficient).

The right solution is to treat time as a one-dimensional space and apply [geo-spatial indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15034024/select-items-within-range-using-mysql-spatial-extensions). In MySQL, geospatial coordinates can only have 2 dimensions - so you need to map the time range into a 2D space. There are lots of examples on the internet of how to do this [with IP addresses](https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/using-mysql-spatial-extensions-for-range-queries/) but I've not seen any specifically relating to MySQL and date ranges. Here is an example [using SQL Server](https://explainextended.com/2009/08/11/efficient-date-range-query-sql-server/).

Interesting to note that you rent rooms by the hour!